# Why different clusterid in orlean server and client could still connect with UseLocalhostClustering?

Tags: .net, orleans

I'm new learning .Net Core orleans, I imitate official sample, here is my code

Silo

```cs
private static async Task<ISiloHost> StartSilo()
{
    var siloBuilder = new SiloHostBuilder()
        .UseLocalhostClustering()
        .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClusterId = "Orleans cluster";
            options.ServiceId = "Orleans service";
        })
        .ConfigureApplicationParts(parts =>
        {
            //host grain
            parts.AddApplicationPart(typeof(HelloGrain).Assembly).WithReferences();
            //load dashboard                    
        })
        .UseDashboard(options =>
        {
            options.CounterUpdateIntervalMs = 30000;
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole());
    var host = siloBuilder.Build();
    await host.StartAsync();
    return host;
}
```

Client

```cs
private static async Task<IClusterClient> ConnectClient()
{
    IClusterClient client;
    client = new ClientBuilder().UseLocalhostClustering()
        .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClusterId = "22";//different but still connected to silo
            options.ServiceId = "11";
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logger =>
        {
            logger.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
            logger.AddConsole();
        })
        .Build();
    await client.Connect();
    Console.WriteLine("[Client]Connect to Silo success");
    return client;
}
```

As you can see,the ClusterId and ServiceId in silo cluster options are different from the sa me config properties in Client,but if I debug silo and client application, client could still connected to silo.
This is MSDN description about Client clusterId, but debug result is conflict with official description? Here is screenshot.
[Connected silo success and also called grain success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUY3b.png)
Could any one help me?
Please accept my best thanks.

Comment: I think `UseLocalhostClustering` ignores `clusterId` and `serviceId` restrictions. Because it's a development setup.